# Linux: How to get Bluetooth peripherals to automatically reconnect when the PERIPHERAL power cycles?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspbian

I'm trying to get an Apple Wireless Keyboard working with a Raspberry Pi 2 (stock Raspbian and BlueZ) such that when I power cycle the keyboard, it reconnects. Is there some way to get `bluetoothd` to do this out-of-the-box without writing my own daemon to constantly check for the keyboard, etc.?

Details: Using `hcitool` and the various `bluez` CLI programs, I've gotten the keyboard paired, trusted, and connected just fine, but when I turn the keyboard off and back on, the connection is lost and I need to plug in a wired keyboard and manually reconnect it.

I must be missing something fundamental, because without fail, every set of instructions I've seen covers how to automatically connect when the COMPUTER boots (and sure enough, restarting `bluetoothd` will connect the keyboard) but nothing about how to reestablish the connection if the PERIPHERAL is power cycled. I'm frustrated because this seems backwards -- my computer stays running, but I want to turn the keyboard off when I'm done to conserve battery life. (Do I have a bad assumption here? I'm not a big user of Bluetooth.)